# Cannot scroll text inside of CardView

Tags: java, android, cardview

I try to make the text "@string/info1" can be scrolled inside of cardView but it did not work. After expanding the cardView, it show all the text which is making the cardView's size be so big. How can I fix this problem?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.infoApp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/cardbackground">
    
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxHeight="200dp"
                    android:onClick="expand"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp"
                    app:contentPadding="20dp">
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/card_layout1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="WHO"
                            android:textSize="30sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#113B68"/>
    
                        <ScrollView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/detail_info1"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                android:text="@string/info1"
                                android:textSize="18sp"/>
    
                        </ScrollView>
    
                    </LinearLayout>
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/icon_layout1"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|right"
                        android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_drop_down_24" />
    
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            </LinearLayout>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

[before expanding cardview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoWoF.png)

[after expanding cardview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm27y.png)

Here a few of screenshot before & after of expanding the cardView.

Answer (score 0):

When height was in wrap_content, it will expand the view itself, So change the height of cardView to fixed height, So it will work as you expected.

Comment: I already fixed the value but it make the cardview's size change & cardview cannot expand. I want make cardview still can expand & at the same time the text can be scrolled

Comment: Then you have to change the size programmatically in Kotlin or Java according to the scenario. If you wish to expand you can expand it by increasing the height dynamically in code.

Comment: alright, I will try it first. Thanks for that idea

Answer (score 0):

do not wrap content the height. do ficed value the height.

Comment: can i know which one that i should fixed value?